# grep N lines after match

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am looking for a command where I can grep 20 or more lines after a specific match.

Example: `grep "09:55:21,651" mylog_file.log`

```
2018-02-26 09:55:21,651 ERROR  [WebContainer : 0] (CommonAction.java:253) - SITAConnector Error: Empty SITA Response XML
com.ac.ccaswitch.exception.SitaConnectorException: Empty SITA Response XML
        at com.ac.ccaswitch.connector.sita.SITAConnector.sendToSitaQueue(SITAConnector.java:144)
        at com.ac.ccaswitch.entry.CommonAction.performTask(CommonAction.java:212)
        at com.ac.ccaswitch.entry.PaymentServlet.doPost(PaymentServlet.java:85)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:970)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
```

Comment: `sed` or `awk` should be able to do this.

Comment: you can find the answer in this cross site duplicate ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern

Answer (score 5):

you can use grep's -An switch to get n lines after the match so for your example that would be

`grep -A20 "09:55:21,651" mylog_file.log`

EDIT:
It looks like your version of grep does not support -A.
So here is a small script you can use instead

```
#!/bin/sh
file="$1"
pattern="$2"
n="$3"
matches="$(grep -n ${pattern} ${file})"
echo "${matches}" | while read match;  do
    line="${match%%:*}"
    sed -n "${line},$((${line} + ${n} - 1))p" < "${file}"
done
```

you can use it like this: `sh script.sh mylog_file.log "09:55:21,651" 20`

EDIT2: While I am at it here is a solution that uses head and tail instead of sed just in case your sed is weird aswell

```
#!/bin/sh
file="$1"
pattern="$2"
n="$3"
matches="$(grep -n ${pattern} ${file})"
echo "${matches}" | while read match;  do
    line="${match%%:*}"
    head "-$((${line} + ${n} - 1))" "${file}" | tail "-${n}"
done
```

Comment: This is not working. I am getting this help content -

abbcd@acsayul000012:/opt/logs$
grep -A 20 "09:55:21,651" CCASWITCH.log
grep: illegal option -- A
usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] pattern_list [file...]
abbcd@acsayul000012:/opt/logs$

Comment: what version of grep are you using?

Comment: How to check the version of grep?

Comment: grep --version or grep -V

Comment: This command is not working.

abc01@acsayul000012:/home/abc01$
grep --version
grep: illegal option -- -

same with grep --Version

Comment: ok from the error message i am guessing that you are running a solaris system. You can either install gnu grep which does support -A or try the script i edited in